# How do I add text to a gtrendsR plot?

Tags: r, plot, gtrendsr

I am trying to make plots using the gtrendsR package. Whenever I try to use the `plot()` function the plot that R returns seems to ignore any text arguments I put inside it like `main=" ", xlab=" " or ylab=" "` and that's my trouble.

I've also tried using `ggplot()` instead.

Here is the code:

```
library(gtrendsR)
library(ggplot2)


fruits<- gtrends(c("Banana", "Apple", "Orange"), geo = c("US"), time = "2019-03-13 2019-03-27")

plot(fruits, main="I tried so hard", xlab="and got so far", ylab="but in the end")

ggplot(fruits)

ggplot(fruits$interest_over_time)
```

But the result was even worse as `plot()` still gives me a graph while `ggplot()` returns nothing.

Answer (score 2):

*I just found this tutorial [Analyzing Google Trends with R: Retrieve and plot with gtrendsR](https://www.datacareer.ch/blog/analyzing-google-trends-with-r-retrieve-and-plot-with-gtrendsr/) that describes the same as I did here but more in depth, this may be a great start for you!*

---

**fruits is no dataframe** 
When you call `class(fruits)` if will give `"gtrends" "list"` to be able to plot it you have to extract the information you want from this object in **dataframe** format. To see what dataframes are in the the object do `View(fruits)` if you are working in Rstudio for example or simply type `fruits$` and hit tab.

[image] 

I have no idea what information you want? But let's say you want to plot the `interest_by_region`, then we get the dataframe by `fruit.df <- fruits$interest_by_region`

**Plotting it** 
Again it is not clear from your question what you want to plot but now you have a dataframe (`fruit.df`) you can plot whatever you want using `ggplot2` for example:

```
fruit.df <- fruits$interest_by_region
ggplot(fruit.df, aes(x=location, y=hits, fill = keyword)) +
  geom_bar(stat='identity') +
  coord_flip() +
  ggtitle("I tried so hard") +
  xlab("and got so far") +
  ylab("but in the end")
```

Which will give you this plot:

[image]
*P.s. credtis to "Linkin Park- in the end" for the main,xlab and ylab hahah*

**Summary** 
So what you have to do is:

- Get a dataframe from the gtrends object, which can be either `interest_over_time`, `interest_by_region`, `interest_by_dma`, `interest_by_city` or `related_queries`. Do this as I described for `interest_by_region`
- Plot whatever you want from this dataframe using ggplot2 (see the [ggplot2 tutorial](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/) if you are not sure how to do so)

Answer (score 1):

You should use `labs` function of the package `ggplot2`  as in :

```
plot(fruits) + labs(title = "I tried so hard", x = "and got so far", y = "but in the end")
```

which outputs :

[image]

**Explanation :**
The fonction plot is used on a `gtrendsR` object and hence the plot method used is `gtrendsR::plot.gtrends` which has the following definition :

```
function (x, ...) 
{
    df <- x$interest_over_time
    df$hits <- if (typeof(df$hits) == "character") {
        as.numeric(gsub("<", "", df$hits))
    }
    else {
        df$hits
    }
    df$legend <- paste(df$keyword, " (", df$geo, ")", sep = "")
    p <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x = "date", y = "hits", color = "legend")) + 
        geom_line() + xlab("Date") + ylab("Search hits") + ggtitle("Interest over time") + 
        theme_bw() + theme(legend.title = element_blank())
    print(p)
    invisible(p)
}
```

as you can see the method use the `ggplot2` package to do the plot (and not R base plot) and already specify the labs in :

```
xlab("Date") + ylab("Search hits") + ggtitle("Interest over time")
```

which needs to be override in your case. For you information, we use the function `labs` instead of `ggtitle`,`xlab` and `ylab` since it is the new way of doing (see https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labs.html) but we could have wrote :

```
plot(fruits) + ggtitle("I tried so hard") + xlab("and got so far") + ylab("but in the end")
```

Comment: Aaah did not know that `gtrends` had its own plotting function (never used gtrends) this is much easier whith less experience in R, good one! Does the plot function you pasted always plots the interest over time?

Comment: yes ! it has to since the returns of `gtrendsR::gtrends` is a list which elements names are  "interest_over_time",  "interest_by_country", "interest_by_region", 
"interest_by_dma", "interest_by_city", "related_topics"  and "related_queries"  and the only way to use the base plot (`graphics::plot.default`) on a list is to have an element "x" and "y" in the list (which is not the case here). Also the output of `plot(fruits)` clearly looks like a ggplot2 plot, which is another tell that a special method plot has been defined for the gtrends object.